# Corrupt VB.Net VS2010 project recovery

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions, corrupt

In the last year I've worked on two relatively large .NET projects and both of them have ended up with project/code generation strangeness that I just haven't figured out how to fix..

The first project generates some bad code for forms that causes the VB.Net build to fail.  I actually had to make a search/replace macro that fixes the 5 problems by adding a **Global.** to the beginning of a few references.

I chalked that up to a random act of unkindness against me and went on my way since the macro takes about 2 seconds to run...

So now 6 months later and new project is cranking along and I get a similar-ish problem.  I have a bunch of form controls that store state in a settings file using the built in capabilities of .Net. I had about 20 controls that were configured automatically this way. Works great until today when for reasons I don't understand in the designer.vb file gets corrupted. At least one other person on the planet has had this problem here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/9bd20b56-7264-4a1f-a379-ad66b372ddd3
but the proposed solution didn't change the behavior.

So now I've had two projects (larger ones) that have project file issues that I can't resolve (I've had several smaller projects that are just fine).

**What tools are available to fix projects, migrate projects, lint projects ... anything to recover projects to a reasonable state? Any successful recovery procedures beyond a roll-back/merge?**

Answer (score 0):

i had a corrupted reference issue linked to my use of mercurial and VS getting lost in file save time... if this may help...

Comment: No use of mercurial here, the project does use devexpress and national instruments code though...as does the older project.

Answer (score 0):

If you open it in notepad and its corrupted - then its probably corrupted and the only way to restore it would be to go to a backup.

--> go to backup

[image]

-->click your project name

-->and then find your fire thats are corrupt